Publishing with azure in VS stuck on Creating: App Service
I am currently trying to publish an application to Azure with an App Service(Windows) through Visual Studio. It has been stuck on Creating: App Service for the last hour.
I tried publishing another app - same problem. I have published a lot of apps before, the same way I tried publishing this one and I never had any problems.


Try to relogin again and check once

This can happen if either your Azure development workload is NOT installed in Visual Studio, or if your Visual Studio is outdated
First, search for and open up Visual Studio Installer from your start menu. Click on Modify and verify if the Azure developoment workload is checked and installed

If this is not installed, try installing this workload and retry your web app publishing.
However if this is already installed, then try upgrading your visual studio to the latest version https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
